# Returning the value of a running total calculator

Tags: c#, asp.net

With the following code I am trying to have a running total value calculated. The first textbox is disabled and is assigned the value of the total after performing the calculation. I am keeping track of all the previous calculations as well.

My problem is this: how can I update the number in the textbox after each calculation? I can't figure out a way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Calculator
{
public partial class Calculator : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = int.Parse(TxtNum2.Text);
        int total = 0;
        string option = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

        if (option == "+")
        {
            total = num1 + num2;                
            lblResult.Text += num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + total.ToString() + "<br/>";
            num1 = total;
            TxtNum1.Text = num1.ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should do some research into using ViewBag (or ViewData) and including its variables into the view. This is pretty trivial stuff that you should research in tutorials.

Comment: This operation would be much better left to client side javascript.

Comment: @SpencerRuport: Given the tax at hand, worrying about client side vs server side is probably thinking too hard.

Comment: How do you like to "keep track of all the previous calculations" ? Do you just want to use the result of the previous calculation?

Comment: yes mshsayem. i am able to keep track of the previous calculations just not updating the first number correctly.

Comment: @Guvante - Simple tasks turn into less simple tasks which eventually turn into complex tasks and then eventually you find yourself asking "Why didn't I just do it the right way to begin with?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `UpdatePanel` like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
...
...

<asp:Button Text="Calculate" runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" />

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtNum1"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This will asynchronously update the value of `TxtNum1`. If you just want to use the result of the last calculation, you can save/retrieve it in the viewstate in `btnSubmit_Click` method. Better make that a property:

```
protected int Result
{
   get
   {            
        return (int)(ViewState["__result"] ?? 0);
   }   
   set
   {
        ViewState["__result"] = value;
   }
}
```

Now you can use it just like a normal field variable (forgetting the viewstate thingy).
Or, if you want *all* the past results you will have to use another data structure (`List<T>` may be?) and just add/save/retrieve to/into/from the viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

can you show your mark up ? have you used `UpdatePanel` ? if not then use update panel and put you label inside it so that it can be update asynchronously.